# How to run a script in ubuntu on reboot

Tags: scripts, cron, reboot

Tried to apply crontab method and other init.d file changes but Not able to run the script using cron and rc.local method

Comment: If you want to run a script via systemd when system reboots , you have to add the [runlevel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runlevel) 6 in the "#Default-Start" of your script as follows : #Default-Start : 6 "

Comment: Can you give me the proper steps

Comment: See my [apache init script](https://pastebin.com/embed_js/y4hYBKDZ) .In the line 7 the Default-Stop is set to 0 1 6 which means apache service will be stopped if you go to runlevel 1 (emergency mode ) or 0 ( shutdown ) or 6 ( reboot ) . You need to specify runlevel 6 in the Default-Start of your init script. However an easier method is to create a crontab with the following syntax " @reboot <command-to-execute> " . It will execute your command when you try to reboot your system . Personally I've never tested the systemd one , but the crontab should work nicely.

Comment: The environment in `cron` is very basic. You need full path to commands or to set `PATH` (inside the crontab) before running your commands and shellscripts. Then it should work with `@reboot` (but first you can test cron with 'run every minute' alias `* * * * *`  to make the testing faster and more convenient.